# launch script hql or sql on hibernate start

Tags: java, hibernate

I remember a function that permits to execute hql or sql script during hibernate startup. Someone remember command syntax? The sql script should be locate in meta-inf with a specific name...

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the 'import.sql' in the root of the classpath file which is executed when hibernate is started in 'create' mode?